# Sorting a generic LinkedList

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have to sort through a `LinkedList`, but i can't figure out why it only sorts it once and then stops. I am having a hard time understanding generic types and how to use them. Most of the examples i found were about sorting integer arrays, but i still couldn't translate those examples into my sort method. Anything that could help me understand how to sort this would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void sort() {

    Node<T> current = head;

    while(current != null){
        if(current.getNext()!=null && current.getItem().compareTo(current.getNext().getItem()) < 0){
            T temp = current.getItem();
            current.setItem(current.getNext().getItem());
            current.getNext().setItem(temp);
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    current = head;
}
```

Here is my LinkedList class

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements LinkedList161<T> {

   protected Node<T> head;
   protected int size;

   public LinkedList() {
      head = null;
      size = 0;
   }

   public void add(T item, int index) {
       if(index < 0 || index > size){
           throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("out of bounds");
       }
           if(index == 0){
               head = new Node<T>(item, head);
           }
           else{
               Node<T> current = head;
               for(int i = 0; i < index -1; i ++){
                   current = current.getNext();
               }
               current.setNext(new Node<T>(item, current.getNext()));
           }
           size++;
       } 


   public void addFirst(T item) {
      head = new Node<T>(item, head);
      size++;
   }

   public void addToFront(T item) {
          head = new Node<T>(item, head);
          size++;
       }

       public void addToBack(T item) {

           if(head == null){
               head = new Node<T>(item);
               size++;
           }
           else{
               Node<T> temp = head;
               while(temp.getNext() != null){
                   temp = temp.getNext();
               }
               temp.setNext(new Node<T>(item));
               size++;
           }     

       }

       public void remove(int index) {

          if(index < 0 || index > size){
               System.out.println("Index out of bounds");
          }
          if(index == 0){
              head = head.getNext();
          }else{
              Node<T> current = head;
              for(int i = 0; i < index;i++){
                  current = current.getNext();
              }
              current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
          }
          size--;
       }

       public T get(int index){

           Node<T> p = head;

           for(int i = 0; i < index;i++){
               p = p.getNext();
           }
           return p.getItem();
       }

       public void clear() {
            head = null;
            size = 0;

       }

       public int size() {
        return size;

       }

   @Override
   public String toString() {

       String result = "";
       if (head == null)
           return result;
       for (Node<T> p = head; p != null; p = p.getNext()) {
           result += p.getItem() + "\n";
       }
       return result.substring(0,result.length()-1); // remove last \n
   }

@Override
public void sort() {

    Node<T> current = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++){
        if(current.getNext()!=null && current.getItem().compareTo(current.getNext().getItem()) < 0){
            T temp = current.getItem();
            current.setItem(current.getNext().getItem());
            current.getNext().setItem(temp);
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    current = head;
}
}
```

Here is my Node class

```
public class Node<T> implements Node161<T>{
protected T item;
protected Node<T> next;

public Node(T item, Node<T> next) {
   setItem(item);
   setNext(next);
}

public Node(T item) {
   setItem(item);
}

public T getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(T i) {
   item = i;
}

public void setNext(Node<T> n) {
   next = n;
}

public Node<T> getNext() {
   return next;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
   return item.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of sort does just one step of sorting: it orders adjacent items and after this step things get better but the whole collection will not be sorted. You should repeat this step until your collection gets sorted.

Note that this algorithm is not efficient. You should look at some more sophisticated approach like [merge sort](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html)

Comment: Does this mean that something is wrong with how i made my while loop? I think that the swapping code is doing what its supposed to do at least.

Comment: While loop is correct but it is not enough to sort whole list with one go. Swapping looks correct

Comment: Yeah that's where i am getting stuck. I thought that the loop would go through until the current.getNext() was null. I don't see why it would stop after just one time through, since I'm telling it to use current.getNext() inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Wiki merge sort article now includes a simple but fast bottom up merge sort for linked lists that uses a small array (usually 26 to 32) of pointers to the first nodes of a list, where array[i] is either null or points to a list of size 2 to the power i. Unlike some other approaches, there's no scanning of lists, instead, the array is used along with a common merge function that merges two already sorted lists. Link to article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists